# How can I write UI Tests/Automation on dynamic framework in iOS

Tags: ios, frameworks, coded-ui-tests, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I have developed a dynamic framework which involves populating view controller and processing of logic. Once the processing is completed framework responds through corresponding delegate methods. I would like to have UI Test implemented on the framework.

we can develop UITesting from a tutorial application leveraging framework but I want to incorporate the UITests in the framework project.(is it possible to Include UITesting in framework Target?)

Any suggestions/ leads of how I can achieve this???

Thanks in advance